# In asp.net mvc How do i use htmlDropdownlist with selected value and onchange event?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How do i load the dropdown list with a selected value there is a also an onchange event?

```
List<SelectListItem> environments = new List<SelectListItem>();

environments.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Development", Value = "DEV"});
environments.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Staging", Value = "STA" });
environments.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "SNL", Value = "SNL"});
environments.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Production", Value = "PROD" });

 ViewData["Environments"] = new SelectList(environments, "Value", "Text", environment);

<p>Select a Deploy to: <%=Html.DropDownList("Environments", (SelectList)ViewData["Environments"], new { onchange = "this.form.action='DeployToChanged';this.form.submit()" })%></p>
```

Comment: I am assuming you will submit the form once the DropDown changes?

Comment: i am assuming you do not mean server side events like Asp.net. right?

Answer (score 0):

are you talking about having one pre-selected when the page loads?

```
new SelectListItem { Text = "..", Value = "..", Selected=true}
```